# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Dear team I am trying to use `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` on my Kotlin application. While running the application, My application got crash, I got the below error,

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.demo.myapp, PID: 25273
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.demo.myapp/com.demo.myapp.ui.main.view.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.demo.myapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #23 in com.demo.myapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3827)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4003)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2317)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8595)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.demo.myapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #23 in com.demo.myapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.demo.myapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.demo.myapp.ui.main.view.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:11)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8207)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8191)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3800)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4003)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2317)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8595)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Here is my code,

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"
    tools:context=".ui.main.view.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/White"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/view_navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        style="@style/BottomNavigationMenu"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**themes.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!--<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/poppins_regular</item>-->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BottomNavigationMenu" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView">
        <item name="android:background">@color/White</item>
        <item name="itemIconTint">@color/menu_text_color_selector</item>
        <item name="itemTextColor">@color/menu_text_color_selector</item>
        <item name="itemTextAppearanceActive">@style/MyBottomNavigationView.TextAppearance</item>
        <item name="itemTextAppearanceInactive">@style/MyBottomNavigationView.TextAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyBottomNavigationView.TextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption">
        <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

**build.gradle (app)**

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Is the crash also happening when you are not specifying the `style`?

Comment: Yes. When I removed style, there is no error.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your app's theme... something like this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

I think the conflict is causing the crash.

Comment: Its not working, I tried the same.

Comment: I mentioned it on gradle implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'

Comment: @SHIDHIN.T.S Sorry, I missed it.

Comment: @SHIDHIN.T.S Try removing declarations inside your custom style one by one to see which one might be causing the crash.

Answer (score 0):

In my case downgrade was solution:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was in the usage of the non-material components parent theme for the activity that contained bottom navigation view. Changing the style from

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

fixed the issue for me.